# segmentation fault joining thread number 5 (pthread_join)

Tags: c, multithreading, segmentation-fault, pthread-join

I'm trying to solve a small problem of synchronization. but when I join the threads i  get segment fault of the fifth iteration! If i only create 4 threads works perfect.

Here I leave the code with some basics of what to do the thread.

```
#include <stdio.h>              
#include <stdlib.h>             
#include <string.h>             
#include <pthread.h>            
#include <semaphore.h>

sem_t HackersEmploy_Counter;
int hackerOnBoat, employOnBoat, B, b, hackerResagado, employResagado;

sem_t Board;
int onBoatId[4];     
char onBoatType[4]; 

sem_t Bote;  

typedef struct{
    FILE* log;
    int ID;
}param;

void* HackerArrive(void* para){
    param* var = (param*) para;
    printf("Create Hacker %i\n", var->ID-1);
    pthread_exit(0);
}

void* EmployeeArrive(void* para){
    param* var = (param*) para;
    printf("Create Employee %i\n", var->ID-1);
    pthread_exit(0);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    sem_init(&HackersEmploy_Counter,0,1);
    sem_init(&Bote,0,4);
    sem_init(&Board,0,1);
    FILE* log;
    log = fopen("result_simulacion.txt", "w");
    int E, e=1, H, h=1, i, r;
    hackerOnBoat=0; employOnBoat=0; b=1; hackerResagado=0; employResagado=0;
    for (i=1; i<argc; i++){
        if (strcmp(argv[i],"-h")==0){
            i++;
            H = atoi(argv[i]);
        }
        if (strcmp(argv[i],"-e")==0){
            i++;
            E = atoi(argv[i]);
        }
        if (strcmp(argv[i],"-b")==0){
            i++;
            B = atoi(argv[i]);
        }
    }
    pthread_t* bank = (pthread_t*) malloc( (E+H) * sizeof (pthread_t*));
    param* var = (param*) malloc( (E+H) + sizeof (param*));
    for (i=0; i<H+E; i++){
        r = rand() % 2;
        if (r==0){
            if (h<=H){
                var[i].log = log;
                var[i].ID = h;
                pthread_create(&bank[i], NULL, HackerArrive, (void*) &var[i]);
                h++;
            }else{
                var[i].log = log;
                var[i].ID = e;
                pthread_create(&bank[i], NULL, EmployeeArrive, (void*) &var[i]);
                e++;
            }
        }else{
            if (e<=E){
                var[i].log = log;
                var[i].ID = e;
                pthread_create(&bank[i], NULL, EmployeeArrive, (void*) &var[i]);
                e++;
            }else{
                var[i].log = log;
                var[i].ID = h;
                pthread_create(&bank[i], NULL, HackerArrive, (void*) &var[i]);
                h++;
            }
        }
    }
    for (i=0; i<E+H; i++){
        pthread_join(bank[i], NULL);
        printf("join %i\n", i);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

run with: `./work -h 4 -e 0 -b 1`

them run with: `./work -h 5 -e 0 -b 1`

if they increase the value of "-h" more than 4 receive segmentation fault

Why this?

Comment: I rolled back to the initial revision. (after spending 10 minutes to find the obvious errors, which I could not find, because they had been fixed) Fixing the errors in the question would make the Q&A worthless for future readers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please be more careful reading your code. This:

```
param* var = malloc((E+H) + sizeof(*var));
```

should be this:

```
param* var = malloc((E+H) * sizeof(*var));
//                        ^
```

Your code works (or at least, doesn't crash) for me after this change:

```
paul@local:~/src/c/scratch$ ./thread -h 2 -e 2 -b 2
Create Employee 0
Create Hacker 1
Create Employee 1
Create Hacker 0
join 0
join 1
join 2
join 3
paul@local:~/src/c/scratch$
```

Using a tool like valgrind would have helped you track this one down in minutes.

As mentioned in my other comment, you should check the return every single time you call functions like `malloc()`, `fopen()`, `pthread_create()`, `pthread_join()`, and so on, otherwise you have absolutely no idea whether you're ignoring important errors your functions are trying to tell you about.

Comment: Good spot - +1.  I didn't notice that there were two errors in the original code.  It took me ages to spot what you'd changed so I've taken the liberty of editing your answer to highlight the problem.

Comment: @simonc: No problem, probably should have thought of highlighting that myself, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The allocation for your array of `pthread_t`s isn't quite right.  You want to allocate storage for an array of `pthread_t` instances but are currently only allocating space for pointers.

By not allocating space for the correct type, you risk writing beyond the end of your allocated memory when you later write to this array.  This has undefined consequences; in this case you're likely to over-write memory used by other parts of your program.  This may well cause a segfault.

You should change the allocation as follows

```
pthread_t* bank = malloc((E+H) * sizeof(*bank));
```

The same issue applies to the `param` array `var` which should be allocated like

```
param* var = malloc((E+H) + sizeof(*var));
```

Note that it'd be good practice for you to `free` these arrays later in your program

```
for (i=0; i<E+H; i++){
    pthread_join(bank[i], NULL);
    printf("join %i\n", i);
}
free(bank);
free(var);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I did what you said but still gives segfault! that could be?

Comment: There's no point asking questions like this until you fix your code. You don't check the return from a *single* one of your functions, not `malloc()`, not `fopen()`, not `pthread_create()`, not `pthread_join`, nothing. If you're not checking whether or not these functions return indicating errors, then you shouldn't be surprised if you get some. You're also not checking if you have valid command line arguments. If you get errors in your code, the first thing you should try is adding proper error-checking to it.

Comment: @CesarJRodriguez See Paul Griffiths answer.  The calculation for memory size of `var` was less wrong but still incorrect in my answer.